# How can i select a table dynamically from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Is there any option to select a table dynamically from mysql..

For example,

If i have 3 tables like

1. **t_tableconfig**
2. **t_2013**
3. **t_2014**

**t_tableconfig** contains data like,

```
tableid  tablename
1         t_2013
2         t_2014
```

**t_2013** contains

```
id     name
1      David
```

**t_2014** contains

```
id     name
1      joe
```

If I will pass a table name as a parameter.. Can I view the records from specified table? Please advice me

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your programming language or ORM(Object-relational Mapping).

Could you please tell me the environment you're using to query sql statement?

// I've added below

As you said you're using hibernate, I hope the link below can help you.
I'm not familiar with hibernate.

[Hibernate: Data Object with a dynamic table name by Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573468/hibernate-data-object-with-a-dynamic-table-name-by-annotations)

Comment: As you said you're using hibernate, I hope the link below can help you.
I'm not familiar with hibernate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573468/hibernate-data-object-with-a-dynamic-table-name-by-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Use [redbeans](http://www.redbeanphp.com/) [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) . it's awesome ORM. you can change your table dynamically. You can perform [crud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operation which you usually use in several tools.

### Advantage

- You can create schema more faster.
- Magically perform [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operation
- That has only 1  php file. It has no criteria to installation.
- Easy to learn