# Can I create Hibernate Envers specific tables using Liquibase

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Our Java app is Spring based and we have domain classes and the corresponding schema generated via Liquibase.

We are planning to add support for a single domain to be audited.

a. We don't have hibernate.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml instead we are using application-context.xml. Then how do I create audit table through annotations like @Audited.

How do I solve this issue? I have added hibernate configuration as

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</prop> -->
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">REV</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">REVTYPE</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.auditTablePrefix"></prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.auditTableSuffix">_AUD</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

Added @Audited annotation in my domain class

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
```

But this configuration did not create audit tables in the development environment. Its not clear what additional configuration I am missing here.

b. How should I create the necessary envers specific schema using Liquibase, the production team is not comfortable with the idea of auto generating the SQL schema as well in the production environment.

Comment: You can manually create the Audit tables when using Envers. So i guess you need to add configuration to liquibase to create those tables.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! If I create audit table manually then how do I getting populate while updating any fields in the original table?

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using? With 4, you don't need any special config to enable auditing, just adding the jar is enough.

Comment: we are using hibernate version: 3.6.3.Final

Answer (score 3):

I use in our project Hibernate, Envers and Liquibase.

The solution to add envers to the entity `ExampleEntitity` with db table `exampleEntitity` (only table, if it is simple entity and we don't audit relations):

**First**, add to liquibase `<changeSet>` tags eg.:

```
<changeSet author="Gal" id="createExampleEntitity_AUD">
    <createTable tableName="exampleEntitity_AUD">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="REV" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="REVTYPE" type="SMALLINT"/>
        (...)
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="Gal" id="primaryKeyExampleEntitity_AUD">
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="id, REV" tableName="exampleEntitity_AUD"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="Gal" id="fkExampleEntitity_AUD_revisionsTable">
    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="REV" baseTableName="exampleEntitity_AUD" 
        constraintName="FK_revisions_exampleEntitity_AUD" 
        deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" 
        onDelete="NO ACTION" onUpdate="NO ACTION" 
        referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="revisionsTable"/>
</changeSet>
```

`id`, `(...)` -> fields from table *exampleEntitity*, which you want to audit.

**Second**, add `@Audited` adnotation to entity `ExampleEntitity` (or `@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)` if you dont want to audit related entities).

That's all. Now all changes of instances `ExampleEntitity` will be stored in table `exampleEntitity_AUD`.

Comment: No need to do anything manually if you are using hibernate >=4.

Comment: @anujpradhan Can you elaborate on your comment? Does Hibernate 4 generate the audit tables automatically?