# Spring Data Envers + Liquibase: how to create audited tables and update them automatically?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, liquibase, hibernate-envers, liquibase-hibernate, spring-data-envers

I would like to audit my models in my Spring Boot app. I use Liquibase for db migration. Say I have this entity :

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class User {
 @Id
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 private String firstName;
}
```

I create the `user` table using Liquibase

```
<changeSet id="user_table">
        <createTable tableName="user">
            <column name="id" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

How can I create the `user_AUD` table used for auditing? I would like to avoid creating it manually because if later I add other fields to the `User` entity I am sure that I will forget to add them to `user_AUD`, and it's too tedious to do it manually. The same question is for the `REVINFO` table (how to auto create it?)

Note that I disabled `hibernate.ddl-auto` property since I use Liquibase.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This question seems to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810697/the-hibernate-envers-with-liquibase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create Hibernate Envers specific tables using Liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059650/can-i-create-hibernate-envers-specific-tables-using-liquibase)

Comment: @JensSchauder Thanks for the link, I already read that post before posting this one. I want to avoid doing what he did in that post, I don't want to create audited tables manually. I have lot ot tables that why I am looking for a way to generate them automatically.

Comment: @akuma8 Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @AnmolVijaywargiya nop unfortunately, I had to create all tables manually! Sad

Comment: Still no solution to this? Is the manual creation the only way?

Comment: @sebasira still, I think the manual way is the only solution.