# how to access table dynamically in spring mvc with hibernate entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Below is my entity class,here i want to access the table name dynamically at run time. Is it possible to access different table with same entity?

I have used following link to solve the problem but no use. 
[Hibernate: Data Object with a dynamic table name by Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573468/hibernate-data-object-with-a-dynamic-table-name-by-annotations)

Please guide me to solve this problem?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tableName")
public class TestClass{

@Column(name="idPerson", nullable=false, unique=true)   
@Id 
...
```

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755260/hibernate-two-tables-per-one-entity

Comment: Thank for your reply. Actually every year the new table will be created, at runtime only i will come to which is going to be accessed. This is my problem.