# How to use dynamic schema names and table names in an Entity class in Java when using Spring boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

This is the **query** I have

```
"SELECT * FROM " + billerInfo.getSchema() + "." + billerInfo.getPaymentTable() + " WHERE STATUS='S' AND BILLER_NUMBER=" Instruction.setString(billerNumber);
```

I need to refactor the project that contains this query using JPA. Time to time the schema name and the table name changes according to the condition.
Columns of all the payment tables are same.

This is what I tried.

This is the **entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class PaymentTable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "BILLER_NUMBER")
    private String billerNumber;

    ...

}
```

This is the **query in repository**.

```
public interface PaymentRepository   extends JpaRepository<PaymentTable,String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM :schema.:table WHERE STATUS='S' AND BILLER_NUMBER=:billernumber",nativeQuery = true)
    PaymentTable getPaymentDetailsWithStatusAndBillerNumber(@Param("schema") String schema, @Param("table") String table, @Param("billernumber") String billernumber);
}
```

I want to know whether this method is correct, and if this is incorrect, the correct method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how to modify the table name dynamically: [Hibernate: Data Object with a dynamic table name by Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573468/hibernate-data-object-with-a-dynamic-table-name-by-annotations)

This documentation shows how to modify the scheme dynamically:
https://www.baeldung.com/multitenancy-with-spring-data-jpa

If you combine those two, I think you might get the desired result!